# TypeScript interfaces and dynamic keys

Tags: typescript, oop, interface

I hope it can be done.

The condition is simple - I have 2 types.

```
type Numbers: Number[];
type Name: string;
```

Let's say they represent data I retrieved somewhere:

```
// first provider sends it like this
{ "numbers": [2, 3, 4], "name": "Mike" }

// second uses different API keys, even though the data type is the same
{ "numeros": [ 7, 8 ], "nombre": "Jose" }
```

I have no idea how API creators named their properties, I just know that the returned payload will have 2 different properties - one with `Numbers` and another with `Name`.

```
interface INumbers {
    [propName: string]: Numbers
}

interface INames {
    [propName: string]: Names
}
```

I know that index signature is used in cases when property name is unknown. It also specifies that there might be more than 1 property. What I'm trying to figure out is if it's possible to join `INumbers` and `INames` together.

I've tried union types, but then the object that implements this interface might have only 1 property. Another idea to extend interfaces did not work as well.

```
interface IPayload {
    [propName: string]: INumbers | INames
}

// this will use `[propName: string]` from 1st extended interface, ignoring others
interface IPayload extends INumbers, INames {}
```

I wonder if it's even can be done. Will appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't know the property names when writing the code, then typescript _can't_ know them either.

Comment: @AlexWayne well that's not entirely true, we see with index signatures that it can be done, the "shape" (or form) of data is more important than the property name.

I'd only wish the `[propName: string]` syntax applied for 1 specific property, not for all properties.

Comment: How would you use this `IPayload` interface? Maybe that would help clarify your question. What is the resulting type you expect that to be?

Comment: @AlexWayne that's a good question, I should have specified it.

I wanted to have object with 2 properties, but I only know what type of data it will have, like:

```interface IPayload {
    [propName: string]: INumbers;
    [propName: string]: INames;
}
```

Comment: But how do you _use_ that? How would you access the property with the numbers if you don't know the property name?

Comment: @AlexWayne ok so it's just an interface. When object **implements** it, it gives required property(ies) name(s). Try to implement `INumbers` interface - your object would not care how you name your property(ies), as long as the data type corresponds to `Numbers`. The same rules apply to `INames` interface - it cares only about data type. Would be great if I could join those 2 interfaces into 1.

Comment: Anyways I've found a workaround for myself, using `class-transformer` npm package.

Answer (score 0):

```ts
type NumberListType = Number[];
type NameType = string;

type NumberKeyType = "numbers" | "numeros";
type NameKeyType = "name" | "nombre";

type INumbers = {
  [propName in NumberKeyType]: NumberListType;
};

type INames = {
  [propName in NameKeyType]: NameType;
};

interface IPayload extends Partial<INames>, Partial<INumbers> {}

const pay: IPayload = {
  numeros: [1, 2],
  name: "",
  // numbers: "", Error
  // nombre: [1, 2], Error
};
```

I try it, It is right you want?
Thanks.